# Android module not open in flutter project

Tags: flutter

I am new in flutter.Why flutter projects which were not created by me did not have iml file and in result i cant open android module in android studio.How to solve this?
I want to set up firebase but this is impossible now
[image]

Answer (score 1):

create file name_project_android.iml in project/android/

iml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="FacetManager">
    <facet type="android" name="Android">
      <configuration>
        <option name="ALLOW_USER_CONFIGURATION" value="false" />
        <option name="GEN_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH_APT" value="/gen" />
        <option name="GEN_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH_AIDL" value="/gen" />
        <option name="MANIFEST_FILE_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" />
        <option name="RES_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/app/src/main/res" />
        <option name="ASSETS_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/app/src/main/assets" />
        <option name="LIBS_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/app/src/main/libs" />
        <option name="PROGUARD_LOGS_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/app/src/main/proguard_logs" />
      </configuration>
    </facet>
  </component>
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/app/src/main/java" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/gen" isTestSource="false" generated="true" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="jdk" jdkName="Android API 25 Platform" jdkType="Android SDK" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Flutter for Android" level="project" />
  </component>
</module>
```